# What is wrong with my List<T>.Distinct()?

Tags: c#, wpf, overriding, gethashcode

I have a class MyItems that implements IEqualityComparer and overrides the following methods:

```
public bool Equals(MyItems item1, MyItems item2)
{
    return (item1.ID == item2.ID && item1.itemName.Equals(item2));
}
public int GetHashCode(MyItems item)
{
    return item.ID.GetHashCode() ^ item.itemName.GetHashCode();
}
```

First, why is `GetHashCode` necessary?  I understand overriding the `Equals` method, however, the `GetHashCode` necessity has eluded me.

Second, this doesn't appear to be working.  Is there something I'm doing wrong here?  Where I don't understand the `GetHashCode,` that maybe where I am tripping up.

Comment: return (item1.ID == item2.ID && item1.itemName.Equals(item2.**itemName**));

Comment: If your `MyItems` class itself implements `IEqualityComparer<MyItems>` there's something wrong. **Either:** Override `Equals(object)` (one parameter) and override `GetHashCode()` (zero parameters). **Or:** Write _another_ class for comparing `MyItems`; the best way is to derive from the abstract [`EqualityComparer<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123.aspx) class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your first question, just look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661801/why-gethashcode-matters) for more information.

To answer your second question: You forgot item2 should be item2.itemName

```
return (item1.ID == item2.ID && item1.itemName.Equals(item2.itemName));
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  Pretty embarrassing, although not uncommon for me, to miss something like this!

Answer (score 6):

The `Distinct` method works as follows:

1. Check if the two objects has the same hash code using `GetHashCode`.
2. If they do, now make sure they absolutely equals with `Equals`.

The `GetHashCode` is a first check for the more expensive check: `Equals`

Your `Equals` method has an error:

```
return (item1.ID == item2.ID && item1.itemName.Equals(item2));
```

Should be:

```
return (item1.ID == item2.ID && item1.itemName.Equals(item2.itemName));
//                                                         ^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, if the List or the array type you're using isn't of `<MyItems>` type you also need to override the Equals method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare objects you should override `Equals(object obj)` in their class.

Also, whenever you override `Equals(object obj)` it is good practice to override `GetHashCode`