# How to store correct Color dialog values to Windows Registry

Tags: vb.net, windows, registry

I am trying to store the Color value from ColorDialog into Registry. 
I am using below code in my utility. However, I notice that when I rerun the utility the Color that get assigned to the `Button1` (value read from Registry on `Form_Load`) is different than what I had stored in Registry in first place.

The Main application for which I have developed this utility has in-built similar feature to save/recall color settings from Registry. I checked that the code in my utility which returns the color from Registry on form load is fine and the color match to what I set through the Main Application.

Could someone please check below code and let me know what's wrong?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim CLR = ColorDialog1.Color.GetHashCode.ToString 

    If Me.ColorDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then 
        Dim regKey As RegistryKey
        regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\MyApp\Settings\Tags", True)
        regKey.SetValue("DefaultColor", CLR, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        regKey.Close()

        Button1.BackColor = Me.ColorDialog1.Color
    End If
End Sub
```

Code used to recall color from Registry:

```
If My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\Settings\Tags", "DefaultColor", Nothing) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("Value does not exist.")
    'creates the DWORD value if not found
    My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\Settings\Tags", "DefaultColor", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
Else
    Dim HEX = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\Settings\Tags", "DefaultColor", Nothing)
    Dim myColor As Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromWin32(HEX.ToString)
    TagLeaderCLRButton.BackColor = myColor
End If
```

Comment: An obvious mistake is that the "CLR" value is obtained *before* you display the dialog.  Writing the wrong value to the registry, the old one.  Move `Dim CLR` *inside* the If statement.  And use Color.ToArgb()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ..I have changed in the code ...

Answer (score 2):

Hash code doesn't represent color.
[Why GetHashCode() matters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661801/why-gethashcode-matters)

```
Dim CLR = ColorDialog1.Color.GetHashCode.ToString
```

Instead, you should use:

```
Dim clr = ColorDialog1.Color.ToARGB()
```

And if possible, use `My.settings` to store Color instead of registry. You can directly store color by creating a setting in project properties. :)

Edit:
`Integer.Parse(HEX.ToString)` is somewhat better than just `HEX.ToString()` right? :)
I don't see anything wrong. If this is your **real** code, you can change it to something like this if necessary. (just an idea):

```
Dim path = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp\Settings\Tags"
Dim defColor = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(path, "DefaultColor", Nothing)

If defColor Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Value does not exist.")
        'creates the DWORD value if not found
        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(path, "DefaultColor", &HFF00BFFF, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
        defColor = &HFF00BFFF
End If
Button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Integer.Parse(defColor.ToString))
```

With this, button1 back color is automatically set to my fav color from the **first** click. he he.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Could you kindly have a look at the other code I am using to retrieve the stored color value on form load which gets assigned to button backcolor... I will add this code in main post..