# MVC LINQ Union with compare IComparer vs IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, list, interface

I have an example class

```
public class Item 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int ItemParentId;
}
```

then I put many Items into the database, there they have an Id, Name and ItemParentId, but I also create a list of new Items, where they have Name, ItemParentId, but Id = 0;

I do select all items from database to list1. I create new list2 with new Items.

I want to make something like this:

```
list1.Union(list2); // need to combine only with different ItemParentId
```

but the problem is that I need to combine only those items, which ItemParentId are not equal. Linq Union only let to create IEqualityComparer, but this one is not suitable. Also I tried IComparer, but Union doesn't let use it. Any help would be appreciated.

Example of lists and what result I want:

```
var list1 = { 
       Item { Id = 1, Name = "item1", ItemParentId = 100 },
       Item { Id = 2, Name = "item2", ItemParentId = 200 },
       Item { Id = 3, Name = "item3", ItemParentId = 300 },
       Item { Id = 4, Name = "item4", ItemParentId = 400 }
  } 

var list2 = new List<Item>{ 
       new Item { Id = 0, Name = "item5", ItemParentId = 500 },
       new Item { Id = 0, Name = "item6", ItemParentId = 300 },
       new Item { Id = 0, Name = "item7", ItemParentId = 400 },
  }
```

result list should contain 3 items, which names are "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4" and "item5"

**UPDATE:**

thanks guys, with your help I managed to compare items by single property, but now I have to do that by two of them. Actually my lass has now 10 properties, but I have to compare only by two, the comparer looks fine, only thing I want to know is what do the HashCode used for?

Comment: Why is IEqualityComparer "not suitable"?

Comment: because it compares two objects, but I need to compare only object parameter, the Id's will never be equal between list1 and list2

Comment: @GrandaS You can write an `IEqualityComparer ` to do whatever you want, including just comparing the `ItemParentId`.  But note that `Union` will still return one of the duplicates.

Comment: It compares two objects in the way it's coded to compare them, you need to compare two Item objects according to their ItemParentId, so create an equality comparer that does that.

Comment: @GrandaS Hm. Why should the result _not_ include "item3"? Seems like it should.

Comment: @Petrichor The OP seems to want a full outer join.  item3 is not included because it's `ItemParentId` is 300 and that value is present in the other list as well.

Comment: woops, my mistake, yes, it should be there too

Comment: @juharr Apparently not :-P

Comment: @GrandaS I updated my answer to touch a little on `GetHashCode`. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems is like `IEqualityComparer` *is* what you want after all:

```
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.ItemParentId == y.ItemParentId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    { 
        return obj.ItemParentId;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
var result = list1.Union(list2, new Comparer())
```

**Update:** If you want to compare multiple properties, you can alter the comparer:

```
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {
        return x.ItemParentId == y.ItemParentId 
            || x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
    {
        unchecked 
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.ItemParentId.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + obj.Name.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

To learn more about the [`GetHashCode`](https://www.google.nl/search?q=gethashcode+msdn&oq=gethashcode+msdn&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1131j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) implementation see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode/263416#263416).

And to learn more about the `GetHashCode` *in general* see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425142/what-is-hashcode-use-for-is-it-unique) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden).

You probably noticed that if you just `return 1` or something from the `GetHashCode` method that your code still works. If you do not implement `GetHashCode` `Union` will call `Equals` which will work but is slower than `GetHashCode`. [Implementing `GetHashCode` increases performance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661801/why-gethashcode-matters)

Comment: The `GetHasCode` and `Equals` should absolutely be based off the same thing.  Basically if two items are equal they should have the same hash code.

Comment: How would I go about doing that if I do not have access to `x` and `y`?

Comment: @juharr I am looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694508/how-to-use-the-iequalitycomparer) and [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/IEqualityComparer.aspx) and they seem to have the same approach as me.

Comment: You have access to `obj` and your `GetHashCode` should be based off of the `ItemParentId` of `obj`, not the `Id` because you compare the `ItemParentId` of `x` and `y`.  Both of your examples use the same property in both the `Equals` and `GetHasCode` methods.

Comment: @juharr Whops. I just confused the properties is all. Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer.

Comment: @juharr Yeah, I noticed that, too. I wrote this before the OP updated his question. Working on a fix now.

Comment: Actually based on the change your answer is correct.

Comment: @juharr not yet, they're using `!=` where the should use `==`.

Comment: @JonHanna That would not produce the desired output.

Comment: @JonHanna Oh yeah, I missed that.  Petrichor you do have to change it.  `Union` will remove items that are equal and you are inverting that.

Comment: Yes it will. They want to find unique cases, which `Union` will give them by filtering out those equal (by the given critera) to those already seen. You have your equality wrong so that won't happen (it'll likely not work well at all because your hashcode will be equal where your equality is not).

Comment: @JonHanna Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Also, you're incorrect to suggest they should move that hashcode into `Item.GetHashCode` (unless they wanted to make this the default way that item are seen as equal, which is unlikely and if so they should just move all of it there).

Comment: @JonHanna Very true. Updated my answer.

Comment: @JonHanna There was also need for me to ` *37`. Geesh. Not my most elegant answer.

Comment: Yeah, the `*37` there just increased your collision count slightly for no gain. I'm guessing you started with a mult-and-add of two or more properties and then simplified?

Comment: @GrandaS No problem mate.

Answer (score 2):

If it's linq-to-objects then you can indeed use an `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class ByParentIdComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
  public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
  {
    return x.ItemParentId == y.ItemParentId;
  }
  public int GetHashCode(Item obj)
  { 
    return obj.ItemParentId;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
list1.Union(list2, new ByParentIdComparer())
```

Will work.

This though won't translate well into SQL. If you might be doing the unioning on a database then you're better off with:

```
list1.Concat(list2).GroupBy(item => item.ItemParentId).Select(grp => grp.First())
```

Which takes both lists (not yet filtering out duplicates), then groups them by the ItemParentId and then takes the first element from each group, and as such gives the equivalent results.

This will also work in linq-to-objects, but the version using an equality comparer will be faster.

Comment: what is that HashCode for? At the moment I have to compare by two properties, but HashCode returns only single, could this be the problem why I don't get what I want?

Comment: Hashcode is used in maintaining a hash-based set of the elements already processed so that duplicates can be identified and discarded. Why do you compare by two properties, your question says you want to be distinct only by one (`ItemParentId`)?

Comment: yes, but it worked fine with single, now I had to add one more property, ItemChildId, and do the same, only make union of all items, where ItemChildId && ItemParentId are not equal, so in the method Equal I can do the job, but how about HashCode, is it important?

Comment: If you don't change the `GetHashCode` it'll work but be sub-optimal (`GetHashCode()` **must** return equal results for objects we are considering equal, but **should** return as many different results for different objects as possible, for more efficient hash-based stores). Try `return unchecked(ItemChildId * 31 + ItemParentId);` for one that should be reasonable enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
        var list1 = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Id = 1, Name = "item1", ItemParentId = 100 },
            new Item { Id = 2, Name = "item2", ItemParentId = 200 },
            new Item { Id = 3, Name = "item3", ItemParentId = 300 },
            new Item { Id = 1, Name = "item4", ItemParentId = 400 }
        };

        var list2 = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Id = 0, Name = "item5", ItemParentId = 500 },
            new Item { Id = 0, Name = "item6", ItemParentId = 300 },
            new Item { Id = 0, Name = "item7", ItemParentId = 400 },
        };

        var listMerge = list1.Union(list2.Where(l2 => !list1.Select(l1 => l1.ItemParentId).Contains(l2.ItemParentId))).ToList();
```

I would personally split that expression in two parts:

```
        var list2new = list2.Where(l2 => !list1.Select(l1 => l1.ItemParentId).Contains(l2.ItemParentId));
        var listMerge = list1.Union(list2new).ToList();
```